# How to host a website in iis7 with www.abc123.com?

Tags: iis-7, hosting

I am new to hosting the website.I hosted the website in my local machine which is fine. I am able to access the applciation with localhost/abc.html.
Now I am trying to access with some name like www.abcsite.com. For this i have given hostname while hosting the website along with the port number. But in this case I am not able to browse the website.
Please help me in this regard.I have referred many sites but not able to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to be more precise in telling what goes wrong, but I'll give it a try. If you have a hosting contract with some webhosting company (ISP), you will have FTP access. You just use some FTP program (e.g. Filezilla) and upload abc.html to the root of your website. www.abcsite.com/abc.html will then give the same result as on your localhost (depending on what it may need further).

Usually you will start a website with a default page which you can set/choose, or is fixed by your ISP, usually default.htm or index.htm. From this page, you refer to other pages.

I hope this helps.

Dick